# Why does my venv seem to install globally?

Tags: python, virtualenv, zsh

For a school project I had to work with a Python venv.
This was not the first time, but when I initialised and activated the venv and did `pip list` it showed my entire global package collection.
So I recursively deleted the whole thing and thought it would be best to simply reinstall all the essentials (numpy, pandas, etc.) globally again and then install only specifics where needed.

Then I found out that no matter where I installed (with venv activated or not), it would always just download globally.
No matter where I `pip list`ed, it would always show the whole thing.
This got me to think that I might have never gotten venvs to work.

I always do:

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

and it will show `(venv)` before the little arrow (or $) implying it works, but it clearly doesn't.

What am I missing?

I am on a M1 MacBook Air, using zsh (oh-my-zsh, but I don't think that should make a difference), Python 3.10.

---

edit:
It turned out to only be the case in one specific venv. When creating another venv the expected behaviour returned.
Still not sure what was the problem though.

Comment: Each `venv` that you make is based on a source environment (in this case, the one that `python3` refers to), and thus comes with everything pre-installed that is in that source environment. Your venv works perfectly fine, as you can test by installing something *in the venv*, and then noticing that it is *not* installed in the system Python. The way to solve the problem (if you consider it a problem) is to not have a "global package collection" in the first place, but instead base your venvs off a fresh Python installation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, I do not understand. 1. Are you saying that it is a bad idea to have numpy installed globally? 2. Yes, when initiating a fresh venv, both python executables that live in this bin directory are aliases to my system python execs (/usr/bin/python(3)). This is fine right? As long as the pip execs are original, all packages that are installed _in the venv_ should appear in the venv's site-packages, but they do not. When pip installing _in the venv_, they somehow appear in the "system Python". Is this the correct behaviour?

Comment: 1. Arguably, yes. At least, if you have it installed globally, then you should expect every venv to have it, too. 2. I don't know what you mean by "this bin directory". 3. No, and it suggests that you have not properly *activated* the venv (i.e. installations that you expect to happen "in the venv" are not doing so). Please re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to check which python interpreter is referred to when running `python3`: to do so, run `which python3` (this should return `path/to/env/bin/python3` if your env was successfully activated)

Each time you want to install a package in your virutal env, make sure to run `python3 -m pip install my_package` instead of `pip install my_package`: this will make sure that `my_package` will be installed for the python interpreter associated to your environment.

Finally, in order to avoid installing by mistake any package on your global python interpreter, add this to your `.bashrc` / `.zshrc`:

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="true"
```

This will raise an error each time you try to install a package to the global interpreter. In order to keep the option to install packages globally, I define the following command additionally:

```
gpip() {
    PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

and run `gpip install my_package` to install it globally.